# What is the difference between mock() and stub() when using Mockito?

Tags: java, mockito

They both seem to do the same thing - why would you use one in preference to the other?

```
org.mockito.Mockito.stub()
org.mockito.Mockito.mock()
```

Comment: the stub method is deprecated, check the docs. The new way of stubbing a method call is what Andy shows.

Comment: ah ok - thanks, that makes more sense!

Comment: @Augusto any idea why `stub` was deprecated? I'm just curious what the key differences are. I tried to find something on the project's mailing list but it's not that easy.

Comment: @toniedzwiedz I think the core idea of the decision is somehow explained in Martin Fowler's blog post [Mocks aren't Stubs](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html). This is not really related to Mockito, but I have the assumption that quite a few of the big brains of TDD were discussing what is a stub or a mock. This obviously is a **big** assumption,  it would be interesting to see the dev discussion list / commit history to get a more factual reason :).

Comment: "They are technically the same thing" - from one of the core Mockito committers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14737131/377384

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use a mock object to verify that you have called it in the way expected. In Mockito, mocked objects are automatically stubs, and verification occurs explicitly.

From Mockito's ["Why do we need another mocking framework?"](http://monkeyisland.pl/2008/01/14/mockito/):

```
 Separation of stubbing and verification. Should let me code in line with intuition: 
 stub before execution, selectively verify interactions afterwards. I don’t 
 want any verification-related code before execution.
```

You can stub the behavior of calls before they're called. For example (from the Mockito home page):

```
 when( mockedList.get(0)).thenReturn( "first" );
```

You can verify interactions with mocked objects after they're called. For example:

```
 verify( mockedList ).add("one");
```

Comment: sorry - i meant the methods,  I have updated title and question.

Comment: I've accepted this answer as it is useful info but the real answer to my question is that given by Augusto - stub() is deprecated.